# C# Selenium Trouble Finding XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

So I am just beginning to learn C#, and I am currently working with selenium. I have used selenium with Python without issues, however I am having trouble finding an element's XPath with C#.

The issue arises when trying to declare the element in the first place. When I use:

`driver.FindElementByXPath();`

I paste the XPath from the button, however C# gives me an error immediately; it looks like it is having trouble understanding the XPath, and I would assume it is because of the quotations.

I have attached an image below. I understand this may be a stupid issue with an easy fix, but all help appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: You should add a + before and after oCartChoose if that's the variable. That's only one of many ways. Other than that using [3] might not be the best way to do it if your html changes later on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use single quotes marks inside double quotation marks.

```
var sizeElement = chromeDriver.FindElementByxPath("//*[@id='oCartChoose']/button[3]");
```

Or vice versa.

```
var sizeElement = chromeDriver.FindElementByxPath('//*[@id="oCartChoose"]/button[3]');
```